# Why is my .cshtml page rendering ViewComponent improperly

Tags: jquery, .net-core, razor-pages

I am attempting to refresh/reload a View Component in a dotnet Core Razor Page SPA.

On my main page I am rendering the ViewComponent successfully using:

```
<div class="row>">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="myButton">refresh</button>
        <div id="timeDisplays" class="row">
            @await Component.InvokeAsync("DateTimeDisplay", @DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString());
        </div>
    </div>
```

But when I put it into a function like so:

```
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    $("myButton").on("click",
        $(function()
        {
            $("#timeDisplays").load(@await Component.InvokeAsync("DateTimeDisplay", @DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()));
            console.log("Reloaded");

        }));
</script>
```

DateTimeDisplayComponent.cs

```
[ViewComponent(Name = "DateTimeDisplay")]
    public class DateTimeDisplayViewComponent : ViewComponent
    {
        public DateTimeDisplayViewComponent()
        {

        }

        public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(DateTime date)
        {            
            return View("DateTimeStringDisplay", DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString());
        }
    }
```

just as an FYI, here is the partial view

```
@model string
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6 text-right">
                <label> Current Time is</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6 text-left">
                <p id="timeDisplay">@Model</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

when the page is loaded, before I ever click on the button, it looks like so:

```
<script>
    $("#myButton").on("click",
        function()
        {
            $("#timeDisplays").load("    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6 text-right">
                <label> Current Time is</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6 text-left">
                <p id="timeDisplay">5/13/2019</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
");
            console.log("Reloaded");

        });
</script>
```

I can kind of tell what is going on.  The invokeasync is returning html but it appears the jquery is attempting to render within the code block.  This is one part I dont understand, why is it executing the function (rendering the html for the ViewComponent) when the page is loading. Shouldn't it wait until I click the button?

I thought about transforming the View into a HTML string, which hopefully the browser can interpret (and I verified works when I replace the invokeasync call with a simple `<p> Hello There<p>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `InvokeAsync` call executes when the page is rendered. You can't call it using JavaScript. It's C#. You can [load a partial via AJAX](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/ajax/partial-update). Perhaps put your ViewComponent into a partial page.

Comment: I'll give that another shot. When I try that I have issues with the Handler method that returns the partial result.